# Haskell Type Level Equality

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

Haskell has a resticted syntax to define type families:

```
(1)   type family Length (xs :: [*]) where
(2)     Length '[] = 0
(3)     Length (x ': xs) = 1 + Length xs
```

On the lines (2) and (3) on the left side of the equal sign (=) we only have simple pattern matching.
On the right side of the equal sign we have just type level function application and as a syntactic sugar 
there are type operators ((+) in line (3)).

There are no *guards*, no *case* expressions, no *if-then-else* syntax, no *let* and *where*'s 
and there is no partial function application. 
This is not a problem, as the missing case expression can be replaced by a specialized type level function, 
that pattern matches on the different cases, the missing *if-then-else syntax* can be replaced by the *If*
function of the [Data.Type.Bool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Bool.html)
package.

Looking at some examples we see, that pattern matching syntax on the type level has at least one
additional feature, not available in normal Haskell value level functions:

```
(1)   type family Contains (lst :: [a]) (elem :: a) where
(2)     Contains (x ': xs) (x) = 'True
(3)     Contains '[]       (x) = 'False
(4)     Contains (x ': xs) (y) = Contains xs (y)
```

In line (2) we use twice the variable *x*. Line (2) evaluates to 'True, if the head of the list of the first parameter 
is *equal* as the second parameter.
If we do the same thing on a value level function, GHC answers with a `Conflicting definitions for 'x'` error.
In value level functions we must add an `Eq a =>` context to compile the function.

Type level pattern matching seems to work similar as *unification* back in the old times of *Prolog*.
I unsuccessfully googled for some documentation about the syntax of type level functions.

- Why does GHC not require something like an *a ~ b* type equality constraint in the definition of the *Contains* type family?
- Is type equality always available?
- Has the type family syntax other additional features, that are unavailable on the value level?
- Where is this documented?

Comment: It is indeed often said that Haskell's type-level language is basically a logical language.

Comment: @leftaroundabout [a bit of fun on that point](https://aphyr.com/posts/342-typing-the-technical-interview) :)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, that only uses *functional* features of the (relational) system, to go with the story that "Haskell" (as they define it) is a functional language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Haskell's type-level language is a purely first-order language, in which "application" is just another constructor, rather than a thing which computes. There are binding constructs, like `forall`, but the notion of equality for type-level stuff is fundamentally mere alpha-equivalence: structural up to renaming of bound variables. Indeed, the whole of our constructor-class machinery, monads, etc relies on being able to take an application `m v` apart unambiguously.

Type-level functions don't really live in the type-level language as first-class citizens: only their full applications do. We end up with an equational (for the `~` notion of equality) theory of type-level expressions in which constraints are expressed and solved, but the underlying notion of *value* that these expressions denote is always first-order, and thus always equippable with equality.

Hence it always makes sense to interpret repeated pattern variables by a structural equality test, which is exactly how pattern matching was designed in its original 1969 incarnation, as an extension to another language rooted in a fundamentally first-order notion of value, LISP.